# Create a nested object with arrays

Tags: javascript

I have an array as below:
Top level category will have parent_category_id to be 0. Sub categories will have property of parent_category_id equal to the respective parent categories.

```js
const categories = [
  {
    category_id: 1,
    name: "Fashion",
    parent_category_id: 0,
    has_category: 2,
  },
  {
    category_id: 2,
    name: "Men's Fashion",
    parent_category_id: 1,
    has_category: 1,
  },
  {
    category_id: 3,
    name: "Men's Fashion - Shoes",
    parent_category_id: 2,
    has_category: null,
  },
  {
    category_id: 4,
    name: "Electronics",
    parent_category_id: 0,
    has_category: 1,
  },
  {
    category_id: 5,
    name: "mobile",
    parent_category_id: 4,
    has_category: 1,
  },
  {
    category_id: 6,
    name: "smart-phone",
    parent_category_id: 5,
    has_category: null,
  },
  {
    category_id: 7,
    name: "Womens's Fashion",
    parent_category_id: 1,
    has_category: null,
  },
];
```

Expected result as follows:

```js
const newArray = [
  {
    category_id: 1,
    name: "Fashion",
    parent_category_id: 0,
    has_category: 2,
    subCategory: [
      {
        category_id: 2,
        name: "Men's Fashion",
        parent_category_id: 1,
        has_category: 1,
        subCategory: [
          {
            category_id: 3,
            name: "Men's Fashion - Shoes",
            parent_category_id: 2,
            has_category: null,
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        category_id: 7,
        name: "Womens's Fashion",
        parent_category_id: 1,
        has_category: null,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    category_id: 4,
    name: "Electronics",
    parent_category_id: 0,
    has_category: 1,
    subCategory: [
      {
        category_id: 5,
        name: "mobile",
        parent_category_id: 4,
        has_category: 1,
        subCategory: [
          {
            category_id: 6,
            name: "smart-phone",
            parent_category_id: 5,
            has_category: null,
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

Could reach only up to second level
attempt:

```js
const findSubCategory = (arr, id) => {
      let result = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i].parent_category_id === id) {
          result.push(arr[i]);
        }
      }
      return result;
    };
    let newArray = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < categories.length; i++) {
      if (categories[i].parent_category_id <= 0) {
        let itemWithCategory = {
          ...categories[i],
        };

        itemWithCategory.subCategory = findSubCategory(
          categories,
          categories[i].category_id
        );
        newArray.push(itemWithCategory);
      }
    }

    console.log(newArray);
```

Can any one help to get the expected result as above.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could build the tree with an object nad store all relation of node and parent and parent and node. At the end get all `subCategory` from the node without parent.

```js
const
    getTree = (data, root) => {
        const t = {};
        data.forEach(o => ((t[o.parent_category_id] ??= {}).subCategory ??= []).push(Object.assign(t[o.category_id] ??= {}, o)));
        return t[root].subCategory;
    },
    categories = [{ category_id: 1, name: "Fashion", parent_category_id: 0, has_category: 2 }, { category_id: 2, name: "Men's Fashion", parent_category_id: 1, has_category: 1 }, { category_id: 3, name: "Men's Fashion - Shoes", parent_category_id: 2, has_category: null }, { category_id: 4, name: "Electronics", parent_category_id: 0, has_category: 1 }, { category_id: 5, name: "mobile", parent_category_id: 4, has_category: 1 }, { category_id: 6, name: "smart-phone", parent_category_id: 5, has_category: null }, { category_id: 7, name: "Womens's Fashion", parent_category_id: 1, has_category: null }]
    tree = getTree(categories, 0);

console.log(tree);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```